# MySQL left join using single row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following tables:

```
mysql> select * from `empresas`;
+----+-------+-----------+-------+------------+----------------+
| id | tipo  | logotipo  | nome  | grupo      | cnpj           |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+------------+----------------+
|  8 | Lazer | troll.jpg | Teste | Pespi Cola | 99999313412312 |
+----+-------+-----------+-------+------------+----------------+

mysql> select * from `empresas_contatos`;
+----+---------+------------+--------------+------------+
| id | empresa | rotulo     | email        | telefone   |
+----+---------+------------+--------------+------------+
|  1 |       8 | Principal  | x@xxx.co.co  | 5112121212 |
|  2 |       8 | Financeiro | fin@y.net    | 5012121212 |
+----+---------+------------+--------------+------------+
```

And I want to get both using left join, like this:

```
mysql> select `e`.`nome`, `e`.`grupo`, `c`.* from `empresas` `e` 
    -> left join `empresas_contatos` `c` on
    -> `c` . `empresa` = `e` . `id`;
+-------+------------+------+---------+------------+-------------+------------+
| nome  | grupo      | id   | empresa | rotulo     | email       | telefone   |
+-------+------------+------+---------+------------+-------------+------------+
| Teste | Pespi Cola |    1 |       8 | Principal  | x@xxx.co.co | 5112121212 |
| Teste | Pespi Cola |    2 |       8 | Financeiro | fin@y.net   | 5012121212 |
+-------+------------+------+---------+------------+-------------+------------+
```

The problem is that in this way the query repeats `empresas` fields, like `grupo`, `nome` (the real table is bigger than the example!).

I would like to know how I could receive all data in a single row. The result should be something like that:

```
+-------+------------+------+---------+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| nome  | grupo      | id   | empresa | rotulo     | email1      | telefone1  | email2      | telefone2  |
+-------+------------+------+---------+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
| Teste | Pespi Cola |    1 |       8 | Principal  | x@xxx.co.co | 5112121212 | fin@y.net   | 5012121212 |
+-------+------------+------+---------+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+
```

And if there is a third `empresas_contatos` row, the query would return `email3`, `telefone3`...

I could use GROUP_CONCAT(), but I'm curious to find a solution for this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially trying to do a `PIVOT`.  The problem here is that we need row identifier to `PIVOT` against.  That's where I've introduced a Row Number Grouped By your empresa column.

So something like this should work, but you'd need to know the max number of potential columns.  But nonetheless, this should help get you started:

```
select g.empresa,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rownum = 1 THEN g.email END) Email1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rownum = 2 THEN g.email END) Email2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rownum = 1 THEN g.telefone END) Phone1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rownum = 2 THEN g.telefone END) Phone2
from (
    select id,empresa,email,telefone,
        @running:=if(@previous=empresa,@running,0) + 1 as rownum,
        @previous:=empresa
    from empresas_contatos t
      JOIN (SELECT @running:= 0) r
      JOIN (SELECT @previous:= 0) s
) g 
GROUP BY g.empresa
```

And here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b19fa/1).

BTW -- it also looks like your rotulo column would need the same logic as it has duplicates.

Here is a more functional working example to match your needs -- I removed empresas_contatos.id, but if you want it, just add another MAX CASE:

```
select e.nome, e.grupo, g.empresa,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rownum = 1 THEN g.rotulo END) Rotulo1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rownum = 2 THEN g.rotulo END) Rotulo2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rownum = 1 THEN g.email END) Email1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rownum = 2 THEN g.email END) Email2,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rownum = 1 THEN g.telefone END) Phone1,
  MAX(CASE WHEN rownum = 2 THEN g.telefone END) Phone2
from (
    select id,empresa,email,telefone,rotulo,
        @running:=if(@previous=empresa,@running,0) + 1 as rownum,
        @previous:=empresa
    from empresas_contatos t
      JOIN (SELECT @running:= 0) r
      JOIN (SELECT @previous:= 0) s
) g JOIN empresas e on g.empresa = e.id
GROUP BY e.nome, e.grupo, g.empresa
```

And more [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fdeac/1).

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much! I made this, based on your reply: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b8c4a/2
But I'm not 100% satisfied, since this query requires a lot of Copy and Paste, hehe. I will try to improve your query to make it more "automatic", but I really appreciate your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @MatheusTavares -- np, glad I could help.  Pivot tables in MySQL are a little more difficult than other RDBMS.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

What is the reason for doing this? How do you use the data after you run this query? Do you import it into a spreadsheet or process it in other ways?

It may be easier to post-process the data to acheive what you want.